# What unit of measure is the Redis server_load stat?

Tags: redis

The Redis INFO command returns a

> server_load

metric, for us this is a value like 0.45. The question is what value does this represent? A percentage? A fraction of 1?

You can see from our monitoring that the load is very low:

[image: Server Load Chart]

Is 0.45 good or bad?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing) most likely

Comment: So a fraction of 1 then where <1 is a good thing?

Answer (score 2):

From https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/investigating-timeout-exceptions-in-stackexchange-redis-for-azure-redis-cache/

> "Is there a high Redis-server server load ? Using the Redis-cli client tool, you can connect to your Redis endpoint and run "INFO CPU" to check the value of server_load. A server load of 100 (maximum value) signifies that the redis server has been busy all the time (has not been idle) processing the requests.Run Slowlog from redis-cli to see if there are any requests that are taking more time to process causing server load to max out."

I think `server_load` only exists in Azure Redis. Haven't seen it in the standalone builds. And i'm pretty sure Microsoft would never use Unix style load indication in ... anything.

No such thing as `server_load` in the source code either:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=server_load

MSOpenTech GitHub Issue link: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/385